# Grails domain class relationship many to one

Tags: grails, grails-orm, hibernate-onetomany

I design domains classes as follow:

```
class Invoice {
   static hasMany = [invoiceOneLines: InvoiceLine, invoiceTwoLines: InvoiceLine]
}

class InvoiceLine {
   static belongsTo = [invoice: Invoice]
}
```

The invoice line has 2 types: `invoiceOneLines` and `invoiceTwoLines`.
Then I create `new invoice line`: I did as follow:

```
def invoice = new Invoice().save(flush:true)
invoice.invoiceOneLines.add(new InvoiceLine().save(flush:true))
invoice.invoiceTwoLines.add(new InvoiceLine().save(flush:true))
```

I created `2 invoice lines as invoiceOneLines` and `3 invoice lines as invoiceTwoLines`. However, when I displayed it in view:

```
invoice.invoiceOneLines.each{}
invoice.invoiceTwoLines.each{}
```

It showed `invoiceOneLines` was corrected but in `invoiceTwoLines`, it showed all(both `invoiceOneLines and invoiceTwoLines`).

I'm not sure do I design correct relationship. I think it should a temporary table(like many to many relationship).

Answer (score 0):

Look at using [mappedBy](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/mappedBy.html).  An InvoiceLine is associated with an Invoice, but in what context - as an invoiceOneLine or an invoiceTwoLine?  As it stands, from the perspective of Invoice, there's no way to know.  mappedBy eliminates this ambiguity.

Hope this helps.